# How to disallow a certain custom gutenberg block outside of an InnerBlocks block?

Tags: block-editor

I did add a custom block as an `InnerBlocks` block, called `slider`. Then i got another custom block `slider-item`. I think you get the idea.

The slider block just allows `slider-item` as it's child blocks. Like so:

```
<InnerBlocks
   allowedBlocks={ [ 'ajk/slider-item' ] }
   template={[
       [ 'ajk/slider-item' ],
       [ 'ajk/slider-item' ],
   ]}
/>
```

Now I want to achieve that an **editor isn't able** to use the `slider-item` outside of my `slider` container block.

Or is there some kind of **repeater block** possibility i do miss?!

---

WP `4.9.8`

Gutenberg `4.2.0`

Comment: The current documentation is lacking in this regard. Your best bet would be to ask on GitHub. You might get a response from devs - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues

Comment: yes, hard to find right docs at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `slider-item` you can specify **parent** must be `slider`.  That way, the `slider-item` cannot be used outside of your `slider` container block.

Something like:

```
registerBlockType('ajk/slider-item', ...
  parent: ['ajk/slider'],
```

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/#parent-optional